# Overriding link style

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

My CSS looks like:

```
A:link { text-decoration: none; color: White; border-bottom:1px dotted white; font-style:italic;}
A:visited { text-decoration: none; color: White; border-bottom:1px dotted white; font-style:italic;}
A:active { text-decoration: none; color: White; border-bottom:1px dotted white; font-style:italic;}
A:hover { text-decoration: none; color: white; border-bottom:1px solid white; font-style:italic; }

#mainmenu A:link { text-decoration: none; }
#mainmenu A:visited { text-decoration: none; }
#mainmenu A:active { text-decoration: none; }
#mainmenu A:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: white; }
```

and in HTML I have:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
   <a href="link here">link</a>
</div>
```

I would think that this menuitem would have the style without text decoration, but instead it gets the underlined style. So the styles for #mainmenu seem to be ignored, it always take the default style.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What broswer are you viewing this in?

Comment: firefox 7, but it's the same in IE

Comment: `#id` styles take precedence over `.class` styles, which take precedence over `a` object styles.  You might want to educate yourself about the cascading part of cascading style sheets :)

Comment: @Set That doesn't explain the problem he's having, as he does expect the #id to take precendence, but the problem is he is not seeing that occur.  He seems adequately educated to me.

Comment: my mainmenu style inherits the base style, so I had to specifically put border-bottom:none; in my main menu so that it doesn't take the base style...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This http://jsfiddle.net/CU9RH/1/ demonstrates that there is no underline for #mainmenu link, but there is a bottom dotted border.

**You will need to override the bottom border if you want it to not show:**

```
#mainmenu A:link { text-decoration: none; border-bottom:none;}
#mainmenu A:visited { text-decoration: none; border-bottom:none;}
#mainmenu A:active { text-decoration: none; border-bottom:none;}
```

Demonstration with fix: http://jsfiddle.net/uYhtw/1/

Comment: allright, that did it! I needed to specifically set bottom border to none! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Curious, CSS is case sensitive (at least with class names and identifiers) and to my knowledge it would be with "native elements" too - but anyway, you can override styles using the `!important` keyword:

```
#mainmenu a:link { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Comment: It should be noted that it depends on doctype and browser as far as case sensitivity goes.  XML or XHTML doctypes will enforce case sensitivity.  You'll have to read up on other potential doctypes, as I'm unsure ;)

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski Good point and yep, definitely worth doing the research.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code

```
#mainmenu A:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: white;  }

A:hover { text-decoration: none; color: white; border-bottom:1px solid white; font-style:italic; }
```

Your `#mainmenu` is setting the underline and color so it's not being ignored if you want #mainmenu to not have an underline then you need to change your code to

```
#mainmenu A:hover { text-decoration: none; color: white; border: 0; }

A:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: white; border-bottom:1px solid white; font-style:italic; }
```

Comment: It's states _other than_ hover which the OP wants to suppress text-decoration for.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I was typing in the OP's code as he had it. Showing the error and I wasn't done editing it yet